# Content: tags contextual filter seems to only match the first tag

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a contextual filter on the field `content: tags` set to "Match any value," but in practice, it appears that only nodes that match the first tag are displayed. For instance a node with the tags "blue, green" would show only other nodes tagged "blue."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting I was missing was under Advanced=>Contextual Filters=>Taxonomy term: Term ID=>More and check "Allow Multiple Values"

Answer (score 0):

It usually work better when you add a relationship to the view, where you relate the content to the taxonomy term. 
Then you unlock a whole new collection of fields and filters.

Choose to filter by taxonomy - name instead of content - tags.

Comment: Thanks Neograph. I added the relationship like you suggested. It still appears to be using only the first tag of the node providing the filter. However the filter returns nodes that have the tag in any position (1st, 2nd, ... nth).

Comment: Just adding the relationship is not enough. After adding the relationship you have to remove the current filter and create a new filter for taxonomy:name instead of node:tags. Your comment implies you only added the relationship.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about my comment. I followed your advice completely and was left with the results stated.

Comment: Do you have aggregation or distinct query results enabled?

Comment: I was mistaken. "Taxonomy: name" didn't provide any results, but "Taxonomy term: Term ID" did provide results that matched the first tag, whether or not the default was set to match "any" or "all" taxonomy terms. The "Distinct" box is not checked under "Query settings." I couldn't find an aggregation setting. Thanks for your help.